# Updating parent record with identity of child record, in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, transactionscope

I have two tables, parent and child. Both have an autoincrement indentity field as primary key. Child has a field that contains the parent's ID, and has a FK enforcing that relationship.

Parent has a field that contains the latest child's ID.

```
CREATE TABLE parent
(
    parentid int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    latestchildid int,
    parentdata nvarchar(256),
    CONSTRAINT PK_parent PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        parentid
    )
)

CREATE TABLE child
(
    parentid int,
    childid int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    childdata nvarchar(256),
    CONSTRAINT PK_child PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        parentid,
        childid
    )
)

ALTER TABLE child
ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_child_parent
FOREIGN KEY (parentid)
REFERENCES parent (parentid)

public partial class parent
{
    public int parentid { get; set; }
    public int latestchildid { get; set; }
    public string parentdata { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<child> child {get; set; }
}

public partial class child
{
    public int parentid { get; set; }
    public int childid { get; set; }
    public string childdata { get; set; }

    public virtual parent { get; set; }
}
```

How do I insert a new parent record and a new child record, and update the latest child field in the parent, in a single transaction?

What works:

```
var parent = new parent
    {
        parentdata = "Some info about a parent"
    };

var child = new child
    {
        childdata = "Some info about a child"
    };

parent.child.Add(child);
dbContext.parents.Add(parent);
dbContext.SaveChanges();

parent.latestchildid = child.childid;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The problem with this is that it requires two transactions.

But if I wrap it all in a TransactionScope, anytime EF decides to use different connections for the various parts, (which is a decision that is pretty much out of our control), it promotes the transaction to distributed, which requires that MSDTC be configured and running on both the user machine and on the database host.  Which is an unmitigated aggravation.

So, can I get the value of childid, and write it to parent, without having to call SaveChanges() twice?

Or can I somehow force EF to use a single connection, for this transaction, so that it doesn't promote it to distributed?

Answer (score 0):

Create another constrain for foreign key relationship between parent and child using the `latestchildid` as primary key

Then add to your parent class `public virtual child latestchild {get; set; }`

Then add the new assignment before the first save changes `parent.latestchild = child;`

Remove the last 2 lines where you assign and save again

Comment: Circular relationships with referential integrity constraints detected.

Comment: what is the EF version? and also can you post the model

Comment: EF 6.0 - and which model do you mean? I posted the EF DTOs, and I can't see how the business layer domain models or the UI viewmodels would be relevant.

Comment: how strong do you need to store latest child id in the parent? unfortunately EF will not allow two entity types that have assocations in both directions, I should of realized that; your 2 options are to have 2 save operations as you have it or derive the latest using linq/expression when needed it

Comment: We are questioning whether we need to.  If the child record is properly indexed, accessing the current child should be reasonably quick.